# Generic stream builder with shapeless HLists

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a simple builder which accepts a `Source` and `Sink`'s from Akka streams and on compile time verifies that a method executed on those has types matching source and sinks.

```
class EventProcessorTask(config: EventProcessorConfig =     
  EventProcessorConfig()) {
  def source[In, MatIn](source: Source[In, MatIn]): SourcedTask[In,   MatIn] = new SourcedTask[In, MatIn](source, config)
}

class SourcedTask[In, MatIn](source: Source[In, MatIn], config: EventProcessorConfig) {
  def withPartitioning[Id](partitioningF: In => Id): SourcedTaskWithPartitioning[In, MatIn, Id] =
    new SourcedTaskWithPartitioning[In, MatIn, Id](source, partitioningF, config)
}

class SourcedTaskWithPartitioning[In, MatIn, Id](source: Source[In, MatIn], partitioningF: In => Id, config: EventProcessorConfig) {
  def withSink[Out, T](sink: Sink[Out, T]): WiredTask[In, MatIn, Out :: HNil, Id, Sink[Out, T] :: HNil] =
    new WiredTask[In, MatIn, Out :: HNil, Id, Sink[Out, T] :: HNil](source, sink :: HNil, partitioningF, config)
}

class WiredTask[In, MatIn, L <: HList, Id, SinksTypes <: HList](
                                                             source: Source[In, MatIn],
                                                             sinks: SinksTypes,
                                                             partitioningF: In => Id,
                                                             config: EventProcessorConfig
                                                           ) {
   def withSink[Out, T](sink: Sink[Out, T]): WiredTask[In, MatIn, Out :: L, Id, Sink[Out, T] :: SinksTypes] =
new WiredTask[In, MatIn, Out :: L, Id, Sink[Out, T] :: SinksTypes](
  source, sink :: sinks, partitioningF, config
)

   def execute[N <: Nat, P <: Product, F, R <: HList, SinksRev <: HList]
   ( executionMethod: In => Future[P])(
     implicit generic: Generic.Aux[P, R],
     rev: Reverse.Aux[L, R],
     sinksRev: Reverse.Aux[SinksTypes, SinksRev],
     executionContext: ExecutionContext,
     l: Length.Aux[SinksRev, N]
   ): Unit = {
    val sinksReversed = sinksRev(sinks)

//    val sinksLength= sinksReversed.length.toInt
}
}
```

The code above compiles but when I try to build a `Broadcast` for the `Sinks` I can't even get the size of the list (commented out code). The next step would be to match all `Sinks` in `SinksRev` to corresponding type from `P` which would allow me to send messages produced by `executionMethod` which returns a tuple to `Sinks` corresponding to `P` types.

I.e.

```
 new EventProcessorTask()
  .source(Source.single("str"))
  .withPartitioning(r => 1)
  .withSink(Sink.head[Long])
  .withSink(Sink.foreach((s: String) => ()))
  .execute(
    in => Future.successful((null.asInstanceOf[Long], null.asInstanceOf[String]))
  )
```

`Long` should go to first `Sink` and `String` to second one.

Any help would be much appreciated. I might be doing something very wrong in here but the concept seemed nice at the time I started working on this (now not so much). Either way I would like to understand what I am missing in here.

To sum up, the questions are:
1. Why can't I get `Int` representation of `SinksRev` size?
2. How to match `Sink`s from `SinksRev` to corresponding elements in `P` to build a `Broadcast` based `GraphShape`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm into shapeless and akka streams recently myself, so I decided to give this question a try. Your case seems pretty complicated, so I took what I understood, simplified it a bit a came out with code that seems to do something similar to what you probably want. I still cannot calculate the length but since it's a builder then `+= 1` could suffice.

Here's the result with Options instead of sinks. It takes list of Options and applies function to the content of options. As I mentioned, I simplified the case.

```
import shapeless._

object Shapes extends App {

  import ops.function._
  import syntax.std.function._

  case class Thing[Types <: HList, Out] private(sources: List[Option[_]]) {

    def withOption[T](o: Option[T]) = Thing[T :: Types, Out](o :: sources)

    def withOutput[T] = Thing[Types, T](sources)

    def apply[F](f: F)(implicit fp: FnToProduct.Aux[F, Types => Out]) = {
      val a: Types = sources.foldLeft[HList](HNil)((m, v) ⇒ v.get :: m ).asInstanceOf[Types]
      f.toProduct(a)
    }
  }

  object Thing {
    def withOption[T](o: Option[T]) = Thing[T :: HNil, AnyVal](o :: Nil)
  }

  val r = Thing
    .withOption(Some(1))
    .withOption(Some(2))
    .withOption(Some(3))
    .withOutput[Unit]
    .apply {
      (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) ⇒ println(x + y + z)
    }

  println(r)
}
```